# uploading files to amazon web server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files using amazon web services, but I am getting this error as shown below, because of which the files are not being uploaded to the server:

```
    {
    "data": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: [\"starts-with\", \"$filename\", \"\"]</Message><RequestId>7A20103396D365B2</RequestId><HostId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</HostId></Error>",
    "status": 403,
    "config": {
        "method": "POST",
        "transformRequest": [null],
        "transformResponse": [null],
        "url": "https://giblib-verification.s3.amazonaws.com/",
        "data": {
            "key": "@usc.edu/1466552912155.jpg",
            "AWSAccessKeyId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "acl": "private",
            "policy": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "signature": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
            "file": "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.giblibion719511/cache/1466552912155.jpg"
        },
        "_isDigested": true,
        "_chunkSize": null,
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, ​*/*​"
        },
        "_deferred": {
            "promise": {}
        }
    },
    "statusText": "Forbidden"
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the reason for the forbidden 403 response? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more details. Which client are you using? From the looks of it, there is a policy that explicitly denies this upload.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're user does not have proper permissions for that specific S3 bucket. Use AWS console our IAM to assign proper permissions, including write.

**More importantly** immediately invalidate the key/secret pair, and rename the bucket. **Never** share actual keys our passwords on open sites. Someone is likely already using your credentials as you read this.

Comment: Slow down.  `AWSAccessKeyId` is **not** sensitive data.  Neither is signature or policy.  There was nothing sensitive in the post that I see, even before it was redacted.  This is a standard form post upload, designed to be visible in the HTML of a web site, which may as well be public.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error: `Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: [\"starts-with\", \"$filename\", \"\"]`.

Your policy document imposes a restriction on the upload that you are not meeting, and S3 is essentially denying the upload because you told it to.

There is no reason to include this condition in your signed policy document.  According to the documentation, this means you are expecting a form field called `filename` that must not be empty.  But there's no such form field.  Remove this from your policy and the upload should work.